# Shifting between two registers in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have two 32 bit integers HI & LO, and I need to right shift bits in them, so that last last bit of HI becomes most significant bit of LO. In other words, shifting operation should work, as if two bits is a single 64bit unit. Language C/C++
Thanks !

Comment: Use the shifting operatings in C.  If you have specific questions post CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below right-shifts 1-bit as you described.

It works by masking off all except the lowest bit in `hi`, and shifting it all the way left (Most Significant Bit), and joining that with `lo` shifted right one-bit.

Then, it simply shifts `hi` to the right one bit.

```
{
    lo = ((hi & 0x00000001)<<31) | (lo >> 1);
    hi = hi >> 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your C has a `long long` (64-bit) type then it is best to use this, but if you need to do it in two halves it goes like this for a logical shift

```
LO = HI & 1 ? ( LO >> 1 ) | 0x80000000 : ( LO >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
HI = ( HI >> 1 ) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

The result of right-shifting a negative number depends on the platform you are working on: it may or may not extend the sign bit. This code caters for either possibility.

Comment: If the values are of unsigned types, you don't need the `& 0x7FFFFFFF` part.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports the `long long` type (i.e. 64 bit integers), you could do the following:

```
unsigned long long joined = (((unsigned long long)hi) << 32) | lo;
joined >>= 1;
uint32_t new_low = (uint32_t)joined;
```

Any decent compiler would recognize the *concat pattern*, which normally would not generate any code. The shift would generate a more or less optimal sequence, and the final cast would, again, typically not generate any code.